# JNI error while running jar from a docker container

Tags: java, docker, jenkins, java-8

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" 
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ***/***/**/***/***(Exception class path)
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
  at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
```

My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM internal-docker-artifactory/ci/maven:3.5.3-jdk1.8.171

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar my-app.jar

ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "/usr/src/app/my-app.jar" ]
```

Is the issue because of the base docker image? The Jenkins build for the git repositery is building fine without any failure.

Comment: You need to provide some more information. What native library are you trying to call using JNI? What's the name of the class that was not found?

Comment: The class not found was an internal class file owned by us. The problem is that the docker build runs successfully. @BenjaminMaurer

Comment: OK, some googling shows that the "JNI error" might be an artifact that you can ignore. So the main problem seems to be, that Java can't find a class in the jar. Can you run the container locally and ssh into it? Maybe check that you can run _any_ java program and verify that the JAR works on your machine.

Comment: I am able to successfully run the jar in my local machine with 0 error code.

Comment: And you run the same Java version on your machine and the JAR has been built with Java 8? Well, then it's probably the container :D Since I don't have access to your Container or even know what's in 'internal-docker-artifactory/ci/maven:3.5.3-jdk1.8.171', I can't help you.